# select text inside an html element and change style

Tags: jquery, css

```
<body>
   text1
 <div> text2</div>

</body>
```

I need to select text1 only and put some styling..

I tried

```
body{
color:red;
}
```

but both text1, and text2 become red.

I'm searching for something like.

```
[css_selector_im_searching] 
{
color:red;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Why dont you cover text1 with some tag and apply style to that particular tag?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap text1 in a `<div>` or `<span>` tag with some id or class or give the css following way..

```
body {
    color: red;
}
body div {
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a always better to enclose text and your other items in containers, it will also help you for specific css styling. See Here

http://jsfiddle.net/NamLd/

```
<div class="div1">   
   Any text you want Here
   <div class="div2">Text Only of This element Div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no CSS selector for textNodes only, but you can wrap the node with javascript

```
$('body').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).wrap('<span class="text" />');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Nes5/)